How can I get my Cassiopeia_child template to use Cassiopeia's template.css?
I have just created a J5.1.1 Cassiopeia child template and in that new template added a user.css, as well as a custom index.php, user.js and sundry override files. It mostly displays correctly, as much of my user.css (copied from another non-child custom template) repeats Cassiopeia and bootstrap css. I was expecting to see the main Cassiopeia template.min.css content used on the front end first and then, if there was a relevant piece of code in my child template's user.css file that overrides it, to use that instead, just like it would if I was just using a user.css file in Cassiopeia. But it's not.
What do I need to do to enable the parent - i.e. Cassiopeia - template.min.css? Thanks.

I found out elsewhere that to get the Cassiopeia template files working as well as your new files in the child template, do this:

Click the 'Create Child Template' button

Select 'Cassiopeia - Default' from the options in 'Additional Template Styles' before clicking the (second) 'Create Child Template' button.

Close Cassiopeia details and files

Go to System > Site Template Styles and you will see two new styles:
'Cassiopeia_template-child-name - Default' and
'Cassiopeia_template-child-name, copy of Cassiopeia - Default'

Select the second one to use Cassiopeia's files as well as your new ones. Any code you create in a 'user.css' or 'user.js' in your child template will overwrite Cassiopeia's as you'd expect.



You can load the content of another user.css or other .css file into the child template user.css via @import, see example:
@import "../../../../../media/templates/site/cassiopeia_child1/css/user.css";
